# Syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chef-infra

Below is my code:

```
    gem_package 'cucumber' do
  clear_sources  true
  source https://chefrubyaehq.kdc.example.com/
  gem_binary '/opt/chef/embedded/bin/gem'
  action :install
end
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
FATAL: zng937-test/recipes/default.rb:43: unknown regexp options - chfrbyahq
FATAL: zng937-test/recipes/default.rb:44: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
FATAL:   gem_binary '/opt/chef/embedded/bin/gem'
```

Does anyone have any idea why I would be getting this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the source (`https://chefrubyaehq.kdc.capitalone.com/`) inside quotes to make it a string. Either single or double quotes is fine for this case.

Answer (score -1):

Just as the message says.

- Your regex `//chefrubyaehq` is invalid. Ruby regex only has `i`, `o`, `x`, `m` options.
- You forgot to put a period after your regex `/\n      gem_binary '/` before the method `opt`.

And when you fix those, you will still encounter more errors.